# Codename one:UI gets change for android and IOS

Tags: mobile, codenameone

I have developed my app using codename one.User Interface of my application looks different in Android and IOS.Some textboxes size gets change .Images looks different in android and IOS .Every thing should display same and properly for all OS.What should I do for that?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That is intentional: https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tutorial-theming-basics.html

You need to override the elements that look different, you can install an Android simulator and preview in both Android and iOS to get the desired result. You can also switch the mode of the designer tool to display the UI as it would appear on an Android device.